# Android app exits without any error in logcat when activity starts

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, logcat

I have created a keyboard and it should start when a button is clicked  but it does not start on samsung tablet my app just exits without any error in logcat but my app works correctly on emulator .Below is my code inside onclicklistener of button

```
String you = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=";
Intent i= new Intent("web.browser.gk.Keyboard");
i.putExtra("websearch", you);
i.putExtra("period", period);
startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE);
```

Can anybody help me identifying the problem

Comment: @ChiragRaval Question title contains "Without any error in logcat".

Comment: If the app is crashing, it probably has some red logcat output. Please give us some more information. Does the device know how to handle a `web.browser.gk.Keyboard` action?

Comment: at least add a log message to onPause(), you should see it. Android may silently kill a process (application) due to a lack of memory, but in this case it should restart the process later.